# docgen: Merge/Append libraries

Tags: dart

How can I create a docgen solution with multiple library packages?  Similar to Dart's, where the left vertical menu contains links to each library.
Example: I have dart editor workspace with 5 projects

```
mowbotnavrc_server (server)
mowbotnavrc_web (client)
mowbotnavrc (library)
mowbotnavrc_protocol (library)
osswebwidgets (library)
```

I'd like the 3 library packages above listed on the left menu from index.html.  As I add more libraries, they each get a link in the left menu. Currently, I can only generate each library separately with no problem.

```
cd %project-folder%
:: <<< Run pub get to get the dependencies >>>
cmd /c %dart-sdk-bin%\pub get
cmd /c docgen.bat --verbose %OPTIONS% --out %ENV-PROJECT-DOCS% --no-include-sdk --no-include-dependent-packages --package-root=%project-folder%\packages %project-folder%\lib
```

The --append option according to the documentation sounds like what I need but I never get it to work.

```
--append
Use the same format used the last time the docs were generated, 
as stated in library_list.json. Add the newly generated documentation
to the docs directory, library_list.json, and index.txt.
```

I'm using Dart SDK version 1.4.0-dev.2.2. I think --append deprecated as of 1.4. Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: I think I read recently that append was or will be removed because it is not working properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add each library file you want to add as an additional argument at the end of the command line.

See [generate-documentation.sh (AngularDart)](https://github.com/angular/angular.dart/blob/2cab2d63ebb92dfeb6b2195853e1376661a95796/scripts/generate-documentation.sh) for an example.

Comment: Thanks! I'm posting a Windows command version based on your suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

Based on Günter's answer, I was able to get a Windows command version working. Maybe others will find helpful as well.

```bash
:: ===========================================================================
:: DOCGEN: MOWBOT Dart Project
:: ===========================================================================
mode con:cols=135 lines=50

:: --------------------------------------------
:: Initialize environment variables
:: --------------------------------------------
setlocal
set PATH-DARTSDKBIN=F:\Public\Downloads\Darteditor-windows-x64\dart\dart-sdk\bin
set PATH=%PATH%;%PATH-DARTSDKBIN%
set PATH-DARTPROJECTS=C:\Users\OSSDevYorgi\DartProjects
set PATH-DARTDOCS=C:\Users\OSSDevYorgi\DartDocs

set ERRORMSG=

:: --------------------------------------------
:: Initialize PATH-DARTDOCS & PATH-DARTDOCS-MOWBOT folders
:: --------------------------------------------
IF NOT EXIST %PATH-DARTDOCS% mkdir %PATH-DARTDOCS%
set PATH-DARTDOCS-MOWBOT=%PATH-DARTDOCS%\mowbot

IF NOT EXIST %PATH-DARTDOCS-MOWBOT% (
   mkdir %PATH-DARTDOCS-MOWBOT% 1> nul
) ELSE (
   del %PATH-DARTDOCS-MOWBOT% /s /q 1> nul
)

:: --------------------------------------------
:: MAIN DOC PROJECT:mowbotnavrc
:: -------------------------------------------- 
set PROJECT-NAME=mowbotnavrc
set PATH-PROJECT=%PATH-DARTPROJECTS%\libraries\%PROJECT-NAME%
set PROJECTLIBS=lib\mowbotnavrc.dart
set PROJECTLIBS=%PROJECTLIBS% %PATH-DARTPROJECTS%\libraries\mowbotnavrc_protocol\lib\protobufs\mowbot.pb.dart
set PROJECTLIBS=%PROJECTLIBS% %PATH-DARTPROJECTS%\webcomponents\osswebwidgets\lib\instruments.dart
::set PROJECTLIBS=%PROJECTLIBS% %PATH-DARTPROJECTS%\webcomponents\osswebwidgets\lib\guages.dart

::set STARTPAGE=%PROJECT-NAME%

:: --------------------------------------------
:: VERIFY FOLDERS EXIST
:: --------------------------------------------
@IF EXIST %PATH-PROJECT% goto :BUILDDOCS
@set ERRORMSG="PATH NOT FOUND "%PATH-PROJECT%
@goto :ERRORHANDLER

:: --------------------------------------------
:: SUBROUTINE:BUILDDOCS
:: --------------------------------------------
:BUILDDOCS

:: --------------------------------------------
:: Hack:Temporary workaround for pre-existing dartdoc-viewer causes "docgen --serve" to fail
:: --------------------------------------------
set ENV-PROJECT-DOCS=%PATH-PROJECT%\dartdoc-viewer
IF EXIST %ENV-PROJECT-DOCS% (
   rmdir %ENV-PROJECT-DOCS% /s /q 1> nul
)

set ENV-PROJECT-DOCS=%PATH-PROJECT%\nobackup\docs
IF NOT EXIST %ENV-PROJECT-DOCS% (
   mkdir %ENV-PROJECT-DOCS% 1> nul
) ELSE (
   del %ENV-PROJECT-DOCS% /s /q 1> nul
)

cd %PATH-PROJECT%
:: <<< Run pub get to get the dependencies >>>
::cmd /c %PATH-DARTSDKBIN%\pub get

cmd /c docgen.bat --serve --verbose --no-include-sdk ^
--include-dependent-packages ^
--out %ENV-PROJECT-DOCS% ^
--package-root=%PATH-PROJECT%\packages ^
--introduction=README.md ^
%PROJECTLIBS%

goto :exit

:: --------------------------------------------
:: SUBROUTINE:ERRORHANDLER
:: --------------------------------------------
:ERRORHANDLER
@echo.
@echo --------------------------------------------
@echo ERROR:%ERRORMSG%
@echo --------------------------------------------
@echo.

:: --------------------------------------------
:: END OF JOB
:: --------------------------------------------
:exit
pause
```